# Render widgets in OpenGL canvas in Java

Tags: java, opengl, widget

Is it possible with Java (and any widget toolkit: AWT/Swing/SWT/...) to render widget within an OpenGL canvas, applying transformations to them while retaining their functionalities and event reactions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.fenggui.org/doku.php

Update: Haven't been many updates to the project. Might be dead, but might be enough for your needs.

I haven't tried it myself but probably better to try this first than cook up your own. If you're going to try your own, I'd go with Swing since it's all internally rendered. The transforms and events will prove tricky especially if you're going beyond 2d opengl.

Comment: Nice, but they have a traditional Win32 look and feel. Is there something that looks a bit more native, à la Swing, on other platforms?

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the same problem of drawing in-canvas widgets for SWT GLCanvas, tried TWL. But because we are using an Eclipse plugin project, it couldn't recognize the .xml TWL use to define a theme. But if you are not using a plugin project, TWL is very promising.